# "\null?" doesn't add a space after the question mark

Tags: tex-core

On the page 34 of the book **TEX for the Impatient**, there is:

> TEX normally adds some extra space after what it thinks is a punctuation mark at the end of a sentence, namely, ‘.’, ‘?’, or ‘!’ followed by an input space. TEX doesn’t add the extra space if the punctuation mark follows a capital letter, though, because it assumes the capital letter to be an initial in someone’s name. You can force the extra space where it wouldn’t otherwise occur by typing something like:

`A computer from IBM\null?`

I tested this:

```
A computer from IBM\null?A computer from IBM?A computer from IBM?A computer from IBM?
\bye
```

The result is:
[image]

`\null` doesn't add a space after the question mark. Did I understand it wrong or did it wrong?

---

If add a space after the question mark,

```
A computer from IBM\null? A computer from IBM? A computer from IBM? A computer from IBM?
\bye
```

The result is:
[image]

I still can't find any difference.

Comment: "*followed by an input space*"

Comment: @campa  I updated my question, and still confused.

Comment: There *is* a difference, albeit small. Enlarge the picture and measure it on the screen `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

The text assumes that punctuation signs

```
. , ? ! ; :
```

are followed by a space, which is the norm in text.

What it says is that TeX (under `\nonfrenchspacing`) will add also some *extra* space.

If you write `?A`, there will be ***no*** space between the question mark and A, because you told TeX not to insert it.

But with `? A` you will see (under `\nonfrenchspacing`) a space slightly larger than the other interword spaces in the line.

However, a capital letter before the punctuation sign would not trigger the extra space. For this you need something that resets the space factor to 1000 and an empty box is good for the job.

```
from IBM? A computer

from IBM\null? A computer
```

[image]

The extra space is a feature of US typography (and also British, to a point). Not customary in continental Europe.

You disable the extra spaces by declaring `\frenchspacing`.

And if you're using LaTeX, ***DON'T*** use `\null` under any circumstance in the body of the document. You'd type the above example as

```
from IBM? A computer

from IBM\@? A computer
```

The command `\@` can also be used after a punctuation sign in order to avoid the extra space in cases such as

```
dr.\@ Treemunch
```

(but `dr.~Treemunch` would be better). Note that `\null` cannot be used for this: you'd need `dr.\null{} Treemunch`.

Comment: Thanks. 1. How do you know this `resets the space factor to 1000` and what is the factor? 2. Why did you add `{}` in `dr.\null{} Treemunch` and can I use `dr.\null Treemunch` instead?

Comment: @Y.zeng You find a description of the space factor in the TeXbook and in TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic`). About the last part, no: if you use plain TeX, do `\def\@{\spacefactor=1000 }` (with a space before `}`, don't forget it). If you use LaTeX, ***don't*** use `\null`.

Comment: Okay. I fount `\null{}` works in LaTeX.

Comment: @Y.zeng I can only repeat my recommendation: ***never*** use `\null` in a LaTeX document body.